# Getting this error on Jenkins - Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, automation

I have added the dependency below on POM file, And this work with no issues on my local.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I tried running this on Jenkins on Remote Repository, it seems that Maven is unable to find it, getting this error below.

[[1;31mERROR[m] Failed to execute goal on project [36mSAMPLE_Project[m: [1;31mCould not resolve dependencies for project sample:SAMPLE_Project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.4 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced[m -> [Help 1]

Comment: Delete your `.m2` folder and try to build again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could only see only one version of `ojdbc6` at `Maven central repository.`

The version you have mentioned doesn't exist there.

Add this to your `pom.xml` and re-build:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then run `mvn install -U`, it will force update your dependencies. Sometimes maven cannot download the dependencies from the central repository unless it is forced.